# Set up pulseaudio to work with USB headset

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, pulseaudio, usb-audio

I've just bought a new headset with USB and P2 connectors and I want to use it in my laptop to play. I'm using Archlinux with gnome and when I plug it via USB it is not detected. If however I plug it via P2 connector I got the audio output normally. I've already followed the instructions for using it with USB on [archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio#Switch_on_connect) but still doesn't work. Can anyone help me configuring it? I need to use it via USB because my laptop doesn't have P2 entry for microphone, only for speakers. Thanks in advance

Output of `lsmod | grep '^snd' | column -t`

```
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     57344   1   
snd_hda_codec_realtek  106496  1   
snd_hda_codec_generic  86016   1   snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_intel          45056   8   
snd_hda_codec          151552  4   snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           94208   5   snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              20480   1   snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                135168  4   snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi
snd_timer              36864   1   snd_pcm
snd                    98304   24  snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm
```

Output of `ls -l /dev/snd`

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root       80 Feb 10 15:41 by-path
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  6 Feb 10 15:41 controlC0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  2 Feb 10 15:41 controlC1
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 12 Feb 10 15:41 hwC0D0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  5 Feb 10 15:41 hwC1D0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 11 Feb 10 15:42 pcmC0D10p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  7 Feb 10 15:42 pcmC0D3p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  8 Feb 10 15:42 pcmC0D7p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  9 Feb 10 15:42 pcmC0D8p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 10 Feb 10 15:42 pcmC0D9p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  4 Feb 10 15:42 pcmC1D0c
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  3 Feb 10 15:44 pcmC1D0p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  1 Feb 10 15:41 seq
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 33 Feb 10 15:41 timer
```

As suggested in the comments:

```
lsusb:
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0cf3:e005 Qualcomm Atheros Communications
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 1bcf:2b90 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc.
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 10c4:8105 Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc.
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 045e:0750 Microsoft Corp. Wired Keyboard 600
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

sudo pactl list short sinks:
No protocol specified
xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused

cat /proc/asound/pcm
00-03: HDMI 0 : HDMI 0 : playback 1
00-07: HDMI 1 : HDMI 1 : playback 1
00-08: HDMI 2 : HDMI 2 : playback 1
00-09: HDMI 3 : HDMI 3 : playback 1
00-10: HDMI 4 : HDMI 4 : playback 1
01-00: ALC3234 Analog : ALC3234 Analog : playback 1 : capture 1
```

No extra output in dmesg, checked it before and after pluging the usb

Comment: Please connect headset via USB, and edit your question with the output of `lsusb`, `cat /proc/asound/pcm` and the additional lines in `dmesg` that appear after you plugged it in (look at the timestamp). If the headset gets picked up properly by the ALSA kernel drivers, also add output of `pactl list short sinks`. (Indent each line by 4 spaces to format for code/output, > is for quoting and will line-break).

Comment: No extra output in `dmesg` means the USB device is not detected **at all**, which points to either a hardware problem or the USB port being for charging in only. In both cases there's not much that can be done. Please verify the device is not detected by comparing `lsusb` with and without the device plugged in; if it's not detected, there should be no change. (There's too many other USB devices for me to do it with the existing output).